# How to get summary for each column of a list

Tags: r, function

Lets take a veriable `cars` as an example. Cars has two columns `cars$speed`, `cars$dist`.

I want to write a function that will print in one step summary for each column of a veriable(in this case cars). It would look like:

```
f<-function(x){
#do some stuff
}
```

The result:

```
name of first column:
 Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
4.0    12.0    15.0    15.4    19.0    25.0 
name of second column:
     Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
       2.00   26.00   36.00   42.98   56.00  120.00
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want is a summary of quantiles and mean, median, then just call `summary()` on your data frame.  It will give you a summary for each column.  If you want to call other functions...

There's a great package for that, `dplyr`.  Take a look at `summarise_each()` and `summarise()`.

Say you want to find the mean of each column and have the output be its own data frame:

```
install.packages('dplyr')
library(dplyr)
new_df <- summarise_each(cars, funs(mean))

## Subsetting to only summarize specific columns
new_df <- summarise_each(cars[, c('speed', 'dist')], funs(mean))
```

You can also compute summaries based on different groups in your data, using the `group_by()` function.  You didn't ask about that so I'll just stop here.

Comment: Looks nice. what about plots? I would like to make a hist chart or density char for each column? How do I do that?

Comment: Ha, I don't mind tutoring, but surely you can google these things a bit.  You can make a histogram in base R using the `hist()` function and specifying which column you want to count.  So, maybe `hist(cars$speed)` or `hist(cars$dist)`.  I forget the density plot call off the top of my head, but I suggest familiarizing yourself with ggplot2, it's fantastic.  If you think my original answer is the correct one, you can use the check mark to mark it as the answer.

Comment: I try to do the same with lapply/apply function. Well I would like to gets histogram of each column and save those hisogram(multiple hisograms in the same file). Do you know how to do this that way? I can't find the anwer  in google.

Comment: Do it in two steps.  Store your plots in a list using lapply/apply, then use lapply with the `save()` function.

Comment: I found function that does exacly what I want. How to simplyfy this?  `multi.hist <- function(x) {nvar <- dim(x)[2]  #number of variables
     nsize=trunc(sqrt(nvar))+1   #size of graphic
     old.par <- par(no.readonly = TRUE) # all par settings which can be changed
     par(mfrow=c(nsize,nsize))       #set new graphic parameters
     for (i in 1:nvar) {
     name=names(x)[i]                #get the names for the variables
     hist(x[,i],main=name,xlab=name) }  #draw the histograms for each variable
     on.exit(par(old.par))   #set the graphic parameters back to the original
     }`

Comment: That's too much for me to tackle while I'm supposed to be working, heh.

Comment: Hehe, Thank you buddy for your help! It was really helpful.

Comment: Just want to note that `summarise_each` has been deprecated in favor of `summarise_all` or `summarise_at`

Answer (score 5):

If you want as output a list

```
f <- lapply(cars, summary)
```

if you want a matrix

```
f <- sapply(cars, summary)
```

Comment: Iit looks really simple. Do you know how to create a chart for each column and save it. I mean each chart in a new file or what would be better multiple plots in the same file? Well, I cant figure it out. If you dont mind turoring it would be helpful.

Comment: @WalterWhite that's a separate issue, consider asking a new question if you dont find a suitable answer `pdf('plots.pdf'); lapply(cars, plot); dev.off()`